# How to check the url in a WebBrowser in windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

In my application,i'm using **WEB BROWSER**. what i want is when a particular web page(url) is loaded, i just want to do an action how can i accompolish this one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mean you're using integrated WebBrowser control in the application??

Comment: Yes i'm using Web Browser control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as you're using **WebBrowser** control in you application you can add **event handler** in **WebBrowser** tag in xaml like:

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="customBrowser" Height="758" Width="480" Navigated="navigatedUri" />
```

you can also use attribute **`Navigating`**

right click on **`navigatedUri`** and then click **Navigate to Event Handler**

it will look like,

```
private void navigatedUri(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //add your logic here
}
```

you want some action to be done after some Uri is loaded, you can check for particular Uri using `e.Uri.Tostring()`, as follows:

```
private void navigatedUri(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs 
{
    if(e.Uri.ToString().Equals("www.google.co.in")
    {
         //perform desired action
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Ask if you have any query. Thanks.

**`EDIT:`**
Sometimes you check for Uri having "**http**" but it loads "**https**" so condition is false. In that case you can check Uri on mobile's **Internet Explorer** and as per that add check conditions. Also you can perform string's `Contains` method i.e. **`e.Uri.ToString().Contains("www.google.co.in")`**. This is totally depends on your requirement, how you want it, how you want to deal with it!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this javascript code, for example:

if(userAgent.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { // Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i
 // your code..
}